# Ansible playbook to install NCPA agent on Windows

Tags: ansible, nagios

I am trying to install Nagios NCPA agent on Windows using Ansible play book. Here is my simple playbook

```
- name: Install NCPA
  win_package:
    path: https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/ncpa/ncpa-2.1.4.exe

- name: Copy the ncpa.cfg template
  win_template:
    src: ncpa.cfg.j2
    dest: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\etc\ncpa.cfg'

- name: Restart NCPA
  win_service:
    name: ncpapassive
    state: restarted
```

However I am getting the below error:

> "msg": "product_id is required when the path is not an MSI or the path is an MSI but not local",

How to I find out the product_id for ncpa?

Answer (score 1):

You can skip `product_id` if you add any of `creates_*` arguments to your first task, for example:

```
creates_path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\___main_executable_file__.exe
```

Or you can search on a machine with your package istalled; per [`win_package` manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_package_module.html):

> `product_id` [ ]
>
> You can find product ids for installed programs in the Windows registry editor either at `HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` or for 32 bit programs at `HKLM:Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`.
>
> This SHOULD be set when the package is not an MSI, or the path is a url or a network share and credential delegation is not being used. The `creates_*` options can be used instead but is not recommended.

Comment: Tried to add creates_path argument, didn't make any difference.   Still getting the error "Missing required argument: product_id"

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to make it work with a  dummy product ID.

```
- name: Create download directory
  win_file:
    path: C:\\Temp
    state: directory

- name: Copy the executable package to download directory
  win_copy:
    src: ncpa-2.1.4.exe
    dest: 'C:\Temp\ncpa-2.1.4.exe'

#- name: Download NCPA executable
#  win_get_url:
#    url: https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/ncpa/ncpa-2.1.4.exe
#    dest: C:\Temp\ncpa-2.1.4.exe
#    force: no
#    skip_certificate_validation: yes

- name: Install NCPA
  win_package:
    path: 'C:\Temp\ncpa-2.1.4.exe'
    arguments: '/S /TOKEN=demo-token'
    product_id: '{ncpa}'
  ignore_errors: true
  register: installmsi
  failed_when: "'was installed' not in installmsi.msg"

- name: Copy the ncpa.cfg template
  win_template:
    src: ncpa.cfg.j2
    dest: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\etc\ncpa.cfg'

- name: Restart NCPA
  win_service:
    name: ncpapassive
    state: restarted
```